# UICollectionView (Horizontal scrolling) Left to right & Top to bottom

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

[image: UICollectionView Layout]

I'm trying to get UICollectionView to layout like the image above.
I've tried setting the scroll direction to horizontal, but that lays out the cells from top to bottom. Is there an easy way of doing this? Ideally I want the same cell size too with 16 px spacing in between.

Can anyone give some insight?

Comment: Check [SMCollectionViewFillLayout](https://github.com/smindia1988/SMCollectionViewFillLayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that someone else shared the same issue and created a flow subclass called `SMCollectionViewFillLayout`. It does exactly what I intended with the following properties:

```c
SMCollectionViewFillLayout *layout      =   [[SMCollectionViewFillLayout alloc] init];
layout.delegate                         =   self;
layout.isHorizontalFill                 =   YES;
layout.stretchesLastItems               =   NO;
layout.direction                        =   SMCollectionViewFillLayoutHorizontal;
[self setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```